# How to rotate a handle shown in the below picture using raspberry pi

Tags: first-robotics, robotics-toolbox

[image]

Need ideas in the direction for to rotate below circled handle to be rotated robotically using raspberry pi etc

Comment: Raspberry Pi cannot rotate the handle ... you need a motor for that ... actually, RPi is irrelevant at this stage of development

Comment: Thanks jsotola , do you think  tower Pro servo motor can do the job !. If not let me know any motor that would do the job

Comment: Hi jsotola , how do I use robotic motor to turn the handle , I could not imagine it , could u kindly elaborate

Comment: difficult to guess what kind of motor would be required ... you said nothing about the control switch ... the picture provides no information really

Comment: At this point I am looking for any ideas or mechanism to rotate the handle and for control switch I just bought l289n motor drive , I am pretty new to robotics that's why seeking for any idea to move the handle programmatically

Comment: you are asking for ideas about an unknown object ... there is no information about the force required to move the lever ... or about the travel angle ... you do not need to know anything about robotics or about mechanics to clearly describe how the lever moves

Comment: Hi jsotola the lever is for a pressing machine and it can turn 180 deg and weighs 300 grams and being used for pressure control and operated by hand .

Comment: Now can there be a some mechanism to turn it with external force using some Robotics , that is where I am literally scratching my head -_-

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134752/discussion-between-papasani-mohansrinivas-and-jsotola).

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Papasani Mohansrinivas, but I'm afraid that *Unbounded Design Questions* are off-topic because there are many ways to solve any given design problem. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask for a list of approaches or a subjective recommendation on a method (for how to build something, how to accomplish something, what something is capable of, etc.) are off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: @PapasaniMohansrinivasP what would happen if the lever was activated unexpectedly? ... could injury or death result?